RNPermissions could not be found
I am new to react-native, and I'm attempting to follow this tutorial https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads. However, I cannot resolve this error. I have found 'fixes' for this and many similar errors, but none have been successful for me. I have been on this issue for days.
I am using the latest of everything.
import { check, request, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS } from 'react-native-permissions';

Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNPermissions' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary. [Component Stack]

EDIT: I'm trying to run on an Android Emulator. I've tried running the command npm start, and I've tried running 'npx expo run:android'

You'll need to create a new development build after setting up react-native-google-mobile-ads. This module contains native code so it will not run on Expo Go.

https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/


It builds, but the build won't start on an emulator.

Have you tried clearing build cache?

Yes, many times.
